# Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes error when using flow_from_directory

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

I have a dataset that consists of 10 subdirectories/ classes of pharmaceutical drugs(each class contains 1000 image) and want to implement GAN on it to increase that size of the dataset but the problem is when i try to load images from its directory

the classes are : Alaxan, Bactidol, Bioflu, Biogesic, DayZinc, Decolgen, Fish Oil, Kremil S, Medicol, Neozep

please note that the dataset is on kaggle

```py
dataset_path = '/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined'
```

this is what I've done so far

```py
# Function to load images from a directory
def load_images(directory, num_images=1000):
    image_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    image_generator = image_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        directory,
        target_size=(224, 224), 
        batch_size=num_images,
        class_mode='input',
        shuffle=True
    )
    images, _ = image_generator.next()
    return images
```

when i load the images like the following

```py
# Load images from each directory
images_list = []

class_names = ['Alaxan', 'Bactidol', 'Bioflu', 'Biogesic', 'DayZinc', 'Decolgen', 'Fish Oil', 'Kremil S', 'Medicol', 'Neozep']
for class_name in class_names:
    directory_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, class_name)
    print(directory_path)
    images = load_images(directory_path)
    images_list.append(images)

# Concatenate images from all classes
all_images = np.concatenate(images_list)
```

the resulting output is :

```py
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Alaxan
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Bactidol
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Bioflu
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Biogesic
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/DayZinc
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Decolgen
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Fish Oil
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Kremil S
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Medicol
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
/kaggle/input/pharmaceutical-drugs-and-vitamins-synthetic-images/Drug Vision/Data Combined/Neozep
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
```

and when i try to print the images from the load_images function, it returns an empty array so i figured that the problem must be with the <kbd>flow_from_directory</kbd> method

to make sure that the images do exist in the subdirectories I tried the following

```py
for class_name in class_names:
    directory_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, class_name)
    print(f"Class: {class_name}, Files: {os.listdir(directory_path)}")
```

and the output was this (i didn't provide all of it as it continues to print out the entire dataset)

```py
Class: Alaxan, Files: ['00000503.jpg', '00000888.jpg', '00000399.jpg', '00000390.jpg', '00000601.jpg', '00000797.jpg', '00000030.jpg', '00000848.jpg', '00000567.jpg', '00000686.jpg', '00000961.jpg', '00000042.jpg', '00000998.jpg', '00000080.jpg', '00000027.jpg', '00000127.jpg', '00000113.jpg', '00000862.jpg', '00000335.jpg', '00000459.jpg', '00000963.jpg', '00000115.jpg', '00000382.jpg', '00000095.jpg', '00000233.jpg', '00000640.jpg', '00000087.jpg', '00000493.jpg', '00000429.jpg', '00000089.jpg', '00000437.jpg', '00000987.jpg', '00000760.jpg', '00000048.jpg', '00000336.jpg', '00000387.jpg', '00000309.jpg', '00000639.jpg', '00000645.jpg', '00000832.jpg', '00000806.jpg', '00000572.jpg', '00000712.jpg', '00000277.jpg', '00000884.jpg', '00000033.jpg', '00000947.jpg', '00000577.jpg', '00000721.jpg', '00000488.jpg', '00000325.jpg', '00000520.jpg', '00000710.jpg', '00000253.jpg', '00000211.jpg', '00000953.jpg', '00000887.jpg', '00000388.jpg', '00000688.jpg', '00000470.jpg', '00000267.jpg', '00000986.jpg', '00000944.jpg', '00000997.jpg', '00000809.jpg', '00000016.jpg', '00000147.jpg', '00000960.jpg', '00000236.jpg', '00000895.jpg', '00000480.jpg', '00000979.jpg', '00000199.jpg', '00000505.jpg', '00000867.jpg', '00000993.jpg', '00000930.jpg', '00000351.jpg', '00000408.jpg', '00000631.jpg', '00000129.jpg', '00000456.jpg', '00000656.jpg', '00000524.jpg', '00000743.jpg', '00000678.jpg', '00000764.jpg', '00000604.jpg', '00000990.jpg', '00000221.jpg', '00000725.jpg', '00000284.jpg', '00000788.jpg', '00000088.jpg', '00000675.jpg', '00000883.jpg', '00000302.jpg', '00000499.jpg', '00000897.jpg', '00000059.jpg', '00000556.jpg', '00000934.jpg', '00000536.jpg', '00000415.jpg', '00000105.jpg', '00000094.jpg', '00000591.jpg']
```

I don't understand where I went wrong and how to improve it

Comment: ImageDataGenerator expects a folder with classes inside (one folder per class), you are doing it incorrectly as you are passing each class folder individually. That will not work.